# Not able to see Salesforce Data event in marketing cloud entry source

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have connected Salesforce with Marketing cloud using Marketing cloud connect but still, I am not able to see Salesforce Data Entry source in Marketing cloud org.

Below is the screenshot for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a provisioning issue - open a Salesforce ticket and they should fix that pretty quick